# InfoWindow not opening immediately

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm having an issue with InfoWindows opening. The code calls the open function but the info window won't appear on screen until the user does something else to interact with the map, usually clicking or moving the mouse.

Here is the intended logic: A info window opens when you click on a marker. If there is already an info window open, it closes the previous one, then opens the new info window. If you click on the map, the info window closes.

Observed Problem: Map loads. I click on a marker and an info window appears. I close it either by clicking on the x on the info window, or clicking on the map.
A) I click on a different marker. Nothing happens. I click again, the info window appears.
B) I click on a different marker. Nothing happens. I click on it again, the info window appears.

Either way an extra bit of user input is required to get the Info Window to appear.

An alternative logic I've also implemented: Have the info window appear after mouseover event fires for the marker. Close only when the user clicks on the map, closes the info window, or runs the cursor over a different marker.

Observed Behavior: Same problem as before, except that the info window will sometimes only appears after the cursor has moved off the marker.

Notes:

- This happens to Polygons as well as Markers.
- Behavior has only been observed in Google Chrome in Windows. No other browsers have been tested.
- This bug has appeared on multiple computers.
- If I use Chrome's developer tools, the Info Window always appears after a breakpoint.

Here is the code:

```
var mCurrentOpenInfoWindow;
var mCurrentInfoWindowParent;

function openNewInfoWindowAtLatLon(parent, anchor, infoWindowData) {
    if (mCurrentInfoWindowParent !== parent) {
        closeCurrentInfoWindow();

        var content = createInfoWindowContent(infoWindowData);
        if (!mCurrentOpennfoWindow) {
            mCurrentOpenInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: content,
                disableAutoPan: true
            });
        }
        else {
            mCurrentOpenInfoWindow.setContent(content);
        }

        mCurrentOpenInfoWindow.open(mGoogleMap, anchor);

        mCurrentInfoWindowParent = parent;
    }
}

function closeCurrentInfoWindow() {
    if (mCurrentOpenInfoWindow) {
        mCurrentOpenInfoWindow.close();
        mCurrentInfoWindowParent = null;
    }
}

// ... Inside a function which creates an adds a google marker 
// in the variable gmarker. displayObject is just an object used to 
// keep the info window from opening multiple times for the same
// map item that has been clicked on.
google.maps.event.addListener(gmarker, 'click', function() {
    openNewInfoWindowAtAnchor(displayObject, gmarker, infoWindowData);
});
```

Comment: I presume openNewInfoWindowAtAnchor calls openNewInfoWindowAtLatLon? Could I see that method? I can't see anything obviously wrong off-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are attaching multiple click listeners to the same marker.

Can you set a breakpoint on `google.maps.event.addListener(gmarker, 'click', function()` in devtools and see if you hit it more than once for each marker?

You could also try using  `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(gmarker, 'click', function()` but I doubt that will solve your problem.

A working reproduction would help figure out the source of the bug.

Comment: This isn't an answer.